# How to load assemblies in different folders C#

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-assembly

I need load a DLL and dependencies. In my database I already save all dependencies (path to the references files).

I.E:

DLL to load:

- id: 1
- name:"DummyModule.dll"

Dependencies:

- DLL id: 1
- path: "C:\DLL\ABC.dll"

AssemblyLoader class:

```
public class AssemblyLoader : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void Load(string path)
    {
        ValidatePath(path);

        Assembly.Load(path);
    }

    public void LoadFrom(string path)
    {
        ValidatePath(path);

        Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
    }

    public void LoadBytes(string path)
    {
        ValidatePath(path);

        var b = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

        Assembly.Load(b);
    }

    public Assembly GetAssembly(string assemblyPath)
    {
        try
        {
            return Assembly.Load(assemblyPath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public Assembly GetAssemblyBytes(string assemblyPath)
    {
        try
        {
            var b = File.ReadAllBytes(assemblyPath);

            return Assembly.Load(b);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void ValidatePath(string path)
    {
        if (path == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("path");

        if (!File.Exists(path))
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("path \"{0}\" does not exist", path));
    }
}
```

The main class:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string file1 = @"1\DummyModule.dll";
        string file2 = @"2\PSLData.dll";
        string file3 = @"3\Security.dll";

        try
        {
            AppDomain myDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain");

            var assemblyLoader = (AssemblyLoader)myDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(AssemblyLoader).Assembly.FullName, typeof(AssemblyLoader).FullName);

            assemblyLoader.LoadBytes(file2);
            assemblyLoader.LoadBytes(file3);

            var dummy = assemblyLoader.GetAssemblyBytes(file1);

            foreach (var t in dummy.GetTypes())
            {
                var methodInfo = t.GetMethod("D");
                if (methodInfo != null)
                {
                    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                    Console.Write(methodInfo.Invoke(obj, new object[] { }).ToString());
                }
            }

            AppDomain.Unload(myDomain);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

In the code above the "DummyModule.dll" is the main dll, "PSLData.dll" and "Security.dll" are the dependencies.

When I call the method "D" of my "DummyModule.dll" the error appears:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'DummyModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

All DLL files still in different folders. How I can load all needed files and call a function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.. it worked for me..

```
serviceAgentAssembly =System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, @"{0}\{1}", assemblyPath, assemblyName));

foreach (Type objType in serviceAgentAssembly.GetTypes())
{
  //further loops to get the method
  //your code to ivoke the function
}
```

Comment: My code stop work in this line "Console.Write(methodInfo.Invoke(obj, new object[] { }).ToString());"

Answer (score 0):

You're using relative paths to the assemblies, so the question is "relative to what?" The new AppDomain you've created and are loading assemblies into is lost in the woods; it doesn't inherit the same probe paths of the AppDomain in which you created it. Take a look at the class *[System.AppDomainSetup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup(v=vs.110).aspx)* and its properties *ApplicationBase* and *PrivateBinPath* along with the form of CreateDomain() that takes an instance of AppDomainSetup as an argument. The simplest solution would be to use the AppDomainSetup instance returned by  *AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation* were the current domain is, of course, the app in which the new domain is created.